# Cannot light portions of object with point light

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, shaders, lighting

I am setting up a simple scene with only a single object, a truck, and a point light. It seems that regardless of where I put the light, the hood (among other portions) of the truck won't be lit. Here's an example:

[image]

My first thought was that it was a problem with the materials on the truck. But the material on the hood is the same as that on the top and sides, so I don't think that it is the issue.

I also replaced all of the materials with the default one (diffuse intensity 0.8 and specular intensity 0.5) to see just the contribution from lighting more clearly:

[image]

Is there some other reason that might be making it impossible to light certain portions of the object?

Other possibly relevant information: In the images above, the light is a bit above the driver's seat of the truck, but the problem remains even if it is directly on top of the hood. I have had better luck with Hemi lights, but would prefer to use point lights if possible. I am using Blender Internal rendering. I am also happy to post more images (the car rendered with shadeless textures, the actual blend file, etc) in the follow-up.

Comment: Check the normals of the model

Comment: Move your light away form the object to get better coverage... if you want your model to look better consider adding a very very  big light source. Lighting cars is an art. See this link to get a few ideas: http://www.zacuto.com/how-to-light-a-car

Comment: @cegaton: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried moving the light away from the model and making it a bit brighter, but I still am unable to light the hood: [example rendering here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw_cfGHqVeqQMElrVU5pRXNMWjA/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I looked into the normals a bit, and found that _Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate Outside_ did change the shading a bit. [Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw_cfGHqVeqQaWI5a3pKVDVaNDg/view?usp=sharing) the new result. Much of the truck is still completely unlit though. Could you point me to a resource explaining how to deal with the normals better?

Comment: If anyone would like to take a look directly, here is a [download link](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bw_cfGHqVeqQWUNXVXRqaFpvNWM) to the blend file. There are only three objects in the file: the camera, a car, and a point light. The car has been decimated a bit to reduce the file size, but I don't think that shouldn't affect the lighting issue.

Comment: Your model seems to have some shading issues beyond a simple one-button-press fix, was this modeled in Blender? I can only take a look at the model later tonight if no one beats me to it.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos No, I imported an obj file from [Shapenet](https://shapenet.org/taxonomy-viewer), so I can't be sure of its origin or how it was modeled.

Comment: Taking a look at your model, it was clearly made in a CAD-like solid modeling or NURBS base software. It has very messy geometry and awful topology, there are sever normal and shading problems that cause these artifacts. I don't think there is any simple one-click-fix for this, other than manually cleaning up. Add an *Edge-Split* modifier to the whole car, *then* separate mesh by chunks with `Ctrl`+`L` > `P` > *Selected*, and recalculate normals afterwards. It seems to be producing some mild results, though it doesn't completely solve all problems

Comment: I believe the light is too close. The Dark areas of the truck are shadows from the lit areas of the truck.

Comment: I'd say it's because of the normals split in a custom way and imported with the mesh, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles

Answer (score -1):

While im not a Pro. I Think, I THINK. You should try increasing the strength of the Light. Or try using multiple lights. I Could also say Try to Transparent the background and Raise the color of the background to a bright color Preferrably a Bright White This will make the Background transparent, And the objects in the rendered image will be Nice and bright.
If you want to have the background grey i won't reccomend the latter.

One of my renders of a character for one of my games. With one default pointlight just above the head, Not bright, I Would like it more bright.  [image]
Now i have changed the Strength of the Pointlight to 900.
As you may notice the ribs are more bright And so are alot of the other parts.

[image]

Comment: I tried increasing the strength of the light (to 1000) and making the background white. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw_cfGHqVeqQd3hOSF9mTGZDMWM/view?usp=sharing) is the result. It seems that the areas that were previously lit are now brighter, but the areas like the hood which weren't lit at all still are completely black.

Comment: You didn't make the background transparent.

Comment: Good catch, thanks. [This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw_cfGHqVeqQZHJYU0x5XzNfRFk/view?usp=sharing) is the version with a transparent background. It unfortunately didn't seem to affect the shading on the truck much though.

Comment: Hmm, Try to send me one with the background brightness lower Still transparent. If it doesn't work then give me the link to the truck and i will show you my attempts.

Comment: [Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw_cfGHqVeqQWlFYMlpsZTZzSlE/view?usp=sharing) the transparent version with darker background. If you'd like to take a look at the model directly, here's the [folder](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bw_cfGHqVeqQTG5ub24xR19hcTQ) with the obj and mtl files, and here it is imported and joined in a [blend file](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0Bw_cfGHqVeqQWUNXVXRqaFpvNWM).