# Strange black shading. Cannot fully light mesh. (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, normals, lighting

[image: The viewport in Material view]

Here is the viewport in material view.  The node setup is just a PNG texture into a diffuse shader.

[image: The viewport in Rendered view]

And this is in rendered view.  I've tried using environmental lighting as well as a directional light, and while the lit parts become brighter/washed out, the darker parts stay dark.

Normals are correct and there is no z-fighting.  Ambient Occlusion is not enabled.  Changing to Flat shading makes it worse.

[Here's the .blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=46088)

Update:  Any modifier that alters the mesh (bevel, subdivide, etc) make the problem go away instantly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have Custom Split Normals Data added to the geometry, to fix this, while selecting the object, go to Data Tab in Properties Panel, scroll to find Geometry Data, and click Clear Custom Split Normals Data.
[image]
More information about this issue [Here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Mont29/Foundation/Split_Vertex_Normals/Custom_Split_Normals_Manual)

Comment: Nice one! I get this a lot when i import obj's from certain pieces of software. And while i have already figured this out, it took me a few months of having to bear with broken normals until i did. Here, have an upvote!

Comment: Glad my answer helped! According to documentation, this happens only when importing .fbx, but the documentation could be outdated.

Comment: it is never this bad but custom normals from an obj can warp your normals