# Wrong shading of surface (normals are OK)

Tags: faces

I would appreciate your help with my model. I'm a beginner so can't figure out how to solve this issue. It's all about wrong shading of the back side of wings and wing flaps (please see attached .blend file below). It is not related to normals but rather to face geometry I believe but how to handle it?

[image]

Comment: Please use only this site to upload .blend files here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Use "auto smooth". You can find this option in the object's properties 'data' tab. But this is a workaround. The main problem is due to the mesh itself: ngons...

Comment: I understand that but I can not see a way to evade using ngons in this particular situation except as to divide one wing flip into 2 separate flips and connect them.

Comment: @VictorA For some reason I can't download the .blend file, but additionally to what lemon said, check that you don't have Custom Split Normals Data added, this might be the reason, specially if your model is imported. check this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles

Comment: @Georges Thank you for the comment. This is not the case as I made this model by myself in Blender from the scratch and did not add custom split normals.