# Shading error after importing

Tags: import, shaders, faces

I am doing a project with some buddies for university and we all work with different Programms and decided to reder the final project in blender, but I am having major shading problems with their 3ds max and cinema 4d imports.
[image]

This is how it looks like with flat shading and I am particulary looking at the thrusters and the Cockpit. And when I turn on smooth shading it looks like this:
[image]
Be aware that there is an edge split on in the last one. But evern if i turn that off it just loks much worse.
The view on the cockpit etc. has these weird shading that almost looks like a few of the verticies are flipped.

For your Information, the whole object has only a single greyish diffuse material on all of it, no glossy or anything. All the faces are looking in the same correct direction.
I am having this problem in many many other files aswell so if you need more information let me know.

Thanks in advance for answers. Best regards.

Comment: Probably related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles

Comment: Yep, also check if normals are pointing in a consistent way, or try to fix them by selecting all faces in edit mode and recalculating normals with `Ctrl`+`N`

Comment: Yep, that was it, really big thanks to you :) upvoted <3