# How can I get Sculptris textures to work in Blender?

Tags: texturing, import

So, a long time ago I asked if it was possible to convert Sculptris files into proper Blender files... with proper texture maps, are able to be baked and re-used. At best, importing the Sculptris object leaves a corrupted texturemap that only half-exists, and cannot be edited much without causing problems.

However, I have managed to find a solution that helps resolve a LOT of this.

**The problem** is that imported Sculptris *objects* retain the Sculptris texture/mapping data, which is incompatible with Blender.

All you need to do is copy the geometry and make a new object. The result is a proper BLENDER object that coincidentally has the same vertices as the import.

Keep in mind my tests have been limited; but I've managed to successfully create proper displacement maps in the UV editor using this technique when previously I could only create a UV mess, so I'm confident this resolves a lot of the issue. I haven't had a chance to experiment so thoroughly.

However, there is still an issue with textures. Please see my reply below for some possible solutions.

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' to the title. Also, a lot of your question seems to be talking about a previous problem in Sculptris you solved. I suggest focusing the question on the problem you actually answered (the textures). This question also seems to be the same as several you asked in the past. This world have been a good opportunity to answer them instead of asking the question again.

Answer (score 2):

For textures, there are more problems; the actual UV texture maps Scultptris makes are a cacophony of random shards that are stitched together only by the object mapping code Sculptris provides.

This is a problem for Blender, which expects textures to be a more unified 'wrapper' (as you know). 
The means, by using the above technique, your texture ceases to be a single smooth surface and instead shows its true form- disjointed shards.

I have two possible solutions;

1- tested and very successful- but a little work intensive.
In short, you flatten the (original) Sculptris model, take a screenshot and use photoshop to put the pieces together. 
**You don't need to do much re-fitting to the UV map IF you specifically use 'squash' type modifiers** that simultaneously flattens the object while spreading it out- often these coincidentally mostly fit the flattened UV map already, at least on simplified objects. It will require a bit of 'hiding' or temporarily deleting vertices so you can squash the surfaces to get some flat angles, so keep in mind as the complexity of the object increases, so does this conversion process.

2- Untested.
It could be possible to bake the original's texture onto a lower poly 'fake' copy positioned over it, but I haven't tried it. If my theory is correct, this should essentially convert the half-pregnant Sculptris texture into a nice, flat Blender one, provided you made the necessary seams on the object to bake onto.

I should point out that at the end of production, you will want to have NO SCULPTRIS files, and everything converted into a Blender UV map, to be applied strictly to BLENDER objects.

I hope this helps, and good luck!