# Flat shaded normals, have weird shading artifacts

Tags: vertices, shaders, normals

I've been working in blender for the past 3 years and never encountered something like this. When I set the normal shading for this object to flat, it shows up like this.

[image]

I made sure the the faces all had the same normals. I tried shading them smoothly and adding sharp edges, that results in the strange smooth normal shading shown below.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know you said you checked, but could you double and triple check the vertex normals? idk what else it could be.

Comment: If object is imported try removing custom imported normals, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles

Comment: Its not imported and I checked the normals again, everything is fine [Normals](http://i.imgur.com/bxGU7BV.jpg) and this doesnt show up on the rest of the model [Rest of Model](http://i.imgur.com/s8DQmXz.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

TL:DR press *Set From Faces* in the *Shading* tab of the *Tool Shelf*.

What's happened is your normals have got bent out of shape in a weird way that the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> *make normals consistent* doesn't see as a problem.

They're all facing the right way vis-a-vis inside/outside, but they're all over the place in terms of direction. So you just tell Blender it needs to force all normals to be perpendicular to their corresponding face.

I still have no idea how this problem occurs in the first place, though. It foxed me for a good few days.