# Face surface/shading looks wrong in a FBX export from sketchup?

Tags: shadows, .fbx

I dont have the original file anymore, of this fbx file that time ago get from the sketchup , and now remade some parts but still looks weird the surface.
If I'm not  worng there is an option to fix these problems, but I dont know what is exactly.
A thanks in advance guys if I can count with your help.

this is the blend file:
https://ufile.io/an4cp

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly why a consider Sketchup such a bad modelling tool, it has absolutely no respect for proper modelling etiquette and good practices. Under the *Object Data * tab of the *Properties Window* check if there are any custom normals and clear them. Also try turning off *Auto Smooth*

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles

Comment: I disabled the Turbosmooth , that was the problem, a LOT of thanks guys!!

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I turn off the *Auto Smooth* and now everything is normal. THANKS !!
[image]

Comment: That is not called "turbosmooth" this is not 3DS Max, that's is called *Auto Smooth*