# Normals seem to be correct but dark spots still appear

Tags: light, normals, shadows

With a lot of the models I have been importing from a game there are dark spots in some places. I removed doubles already and recalculated normals, but I still get this when rendering:

[image]

The dark spots are on the top and bottom walls on the right side. It's not a shadow because moving the sun lamp and even using ambient occlusion does nothing. I checked the normals, but they look fine.

[image]

The only things I can thing of that make this (imported) object different from one made from scratch are that it is already triangulated since it is a game asset, and it has sharps, which I have been told can store data. I'm probably missing something here; I've never seen this before though.

[image]

Comment: See this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5441/26720

Comment: Try https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles

Comment: Pressing the clear custom split button as suggested in the other thread seems to repair that.