# how to correctly import .wrl in blender?

Tags: import, unreal-engine

I basically know how to import this type of file (file-> import-> X3D Extensible) but when i do this with a wrl file i got from DSI Studio (Program to track brainfibres) the fibres show weird dark triangles. if i open the same file in windows' own 3D Builder app the fibres apper as nice as in DSI Studio (lack of color ignored)

So what do i do wrong? is blender the problem? could you suggest annother program to convert the wrl file to an fbx file? i want to use the 3d model for a game being developed in the unreal engine 4.

I put some images in for clarification. first is blender, second is windows 3d builder.

Hopefully someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

[image: blender]

[image: 3dbuilder]

Comment: i was not allowed to post more than 2 links in one post. here is a link to a picture of the original source of the wrl file (DSI Studio)
http://imgur.com/a/ReIcN

Comment: This is likely a geometry problem with the model itself, like inverted normals, duplicate vertex or internal faces, and not a problem with the import process procedure

Comment: Try removing split normals, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles. Note though that could change the look of the model and probably you might need to split normals again somehow.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos do you know a way how i clould solve the problems you think the model could have?

Comment: @MrZak I tried to do what you suggested, but i could not clear the normals data, just add custom normals data. I did it that, nothing changed, then cleared the data, again nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it!

I have selected the model in blender, changed to from object to edit mode, then pressed ctrl + n and. after that on the lower left hand side appeared "Make Normals Consistent" with a checkbox "Inside". clicked that, exported as fbx, imported in ue4 and everything looks fine.

Thank you for your help!

[image]