# Lightroom does not light evenly - Weird light reflections (Cycles) (.blend attached)

Tags: rendering, materials, light, lighting

I am trying to light my car in a way that the background is quite dark and/but the car has some sharp reflections. I found a Lightroom that I really like because of it^s reflecting floor/walls. The problem is that the top of the car is still pitch black and is not affected by the lights, I can x10 the light emission and still get no difference in that part of the car. There are also some weird light reflections, but I don^t think there is a simple fix to them.

The .blend file (Scene 2) (pasteall did not work so i needed another host): https://www.sendspace.com/file/uhli8d

[image: render]

Comment: Maybe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles. If the lighting is that much dark and lacking reflections then it's too early to refine render in image processing applications, it's best to get as much from the scene as you can. To upload files on this site use [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: Thank you, it helped... Any idea how I can get rid of the weird reflections?

Comment: Reflections depend on the objects present in your scene, materials they have and lighting. Inspect the scene for the duplicate / hidden objects or any problems like z-fighting, try setting up proper materials for them (Local View can be handy) and setup lighting which will produce multiple reflections from different angles (start with 3 point light maybe).

Comment: The material used on the floor/walls is of the type Glossy with roughness set to zero, increase the roughness or change the material entirely to get rid of the weirdness. :)

Comment: @TobiasE the thing is I like the glossy floor, is there a way to keep the reflections of the car and get rid of the others? :)

Comment: @Luca I think you be better of if you replace the rounded box with a simple plane plane instead (using the same material). It is the walls of the cube that are responsible for the reflections from the lights.