# Strangely behaving texture/material

Tags: texturing

Seeking some help; I lack the vocabulary to describe what is happening. I tried recalculating the normals, but otherwise at a bit of a loss.

Edit: I downloaded this from a free 3d model site, it was in .blend format already. It only happens when I switch from ortho to perspective. There is no option to 'clear custom split normals data' only to 'add'

[image]

Comment: It is not that hard to describe: "I imported a model created in [...] , the model was saved as [....] format. When I open it in blender it looks triangulated and with random black faces". Most likely you are dealing with custom split normals or/and duplicated geometry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Strange black shading](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles) or [using an imported model why does my mesh look like this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96309/using-an-imported-model-why-does-my-mesh-look-like-this/96317#96317)

Comment: @cegaton that's incorrect, it was made in Blender and opened as such. Thanks for the other half of your comment

Comment: well that is what happens when a question is vague... guessing is likely to create confusion and errors. That is why we ask users to expand on their questions and be as precise as they can. Showing an image is not enough, as is open to interpretation. Not everyone will see the same thing...

Comment: Perhaps someone out there can tell me what this sort of artifact/behavior is called so that I can look around for it?