# Mesh with weird inverted light direction

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

Sometimes while editing meshes I get stuck with a weird kind of behaviour. I know mostly it happens due to my fault as a newby, but I need find the way to fix it.

Step by step explanation appreciated.

[image]

https://www.sendspace.com/file/7pyhz1

Comment: Hope this helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange black shading. Cannot fully light mesh. (Cycles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles)

Comment: Are your [normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/12174/2217) correct?

Comment: Yes, normals were ok, Mike`s solution helped me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obj file has bad normal data for some reason, which gets imported into Blender. The way to fix it is to delete any custom normal data using the 'Clear Custom Split Normal' button from the object data panel.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks for quick reply, very helpful!

Answer (score -1):

When some faces look dark on a mirrored side of a mesh put your mouse in the 3D view and press 'n' to toggle the right side menu to appear and then 'tab' to edit mode.
Scroll down the properties column till you find the Mesh Display, you'll find 
Normals: Click on the cube, that's for the faces.
The lines stick out of the facing faces. If some are facing the wrong way they are inverted and the back side will look dark. The normals indicator will help you determine that.

You have 2 choices:
1 try selecting the entire mesh then use the Recalculate in the Shading/UV tab in the left side menu, press  't' to toggle that menu to appear.
2 If that doesn't work select only the face that are inverted and choose Flip Direction.

Comment: I took a look at the files, and strangely enough the normals actually look alright. The problem doesn't seem to be coming from the material, either. https://i.imgur.com/tvv5Txz.png It's got to be something else.

Comment: In fact, this is what the model looks like with flat shading. I haven't a clue what's going on here. https://i.imgur.com/NgJg61Y.png

Comment: Oh I see now, Delete the mesh data. In the properties tab scroll down to the Geometry Data and delete all the mesh data on the 3 buttons. That is weirdness is usually found in imported mesh. See if that works.

Comment: Yes, Clear Custom Split Normals Data and after Add Custom Split Normals in Geometry Data helps me as stated in Mike`s reply. And I did it many times before posting this issue and my mistake was that I was doing this with mesh that became weird after some manipulation with it (mirror or whatever), but correct solution is to do all that stuff with the rest meshes. Thanks!

Comment: In my case that one mesh was Vertical Stabilizer Rudder, and the rest meshes - all the rest aircraft parts.