# Dark artifacts while rendering

Tags: rendering, modifiers, artifacts

I have tried recalculating the normals, added an Edge split modifier and tried the Subsurf Modifier too, but none of them seem to remove the dark artifacts around the edges.

Increasing the transmission and glossy bounces also have no effect.
Please suggest what I can do to remove them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: your normals are a mess. You need to [make normals consistent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/12165/2217).

Comment: Or Clear Split Normals: [Strange black shading. Cannot fully light mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles)

Comment: I made the normals consistent, and checked to see that there were no Split Normals. I still see the issue.
Can you have a look at the blend file here?
http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=49154