# My object mesh have some sort of serious tile pattern glitch

Tags: mesh, materials

[image: This is the object with the default material.]

I think the problem I have has something to do with overlapping faces, because the pattern becomes more repeated each time i subdivide the object. I have tried to delete double vertices and recalculate normals to no end. However, the pattern disappears when i go into Sculpt mode, and the pattern stays no matter what material I assign to it. The pattern is still visible when the object is rendered.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles

Comment: Nevermind! I found the answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/)