# Why won't only some parts of my textured mesh render?

Tags: rendering, texturing, color

I realize this might seem a little like some other posts I have read, but I have a slightly different problem. I painted a model and tried a test render. Only some of the colors showed up. A near black one appears to be brighter than a skin colored one. all of the colors are in the same image. I think I have unwrapped everything correctly, as some of the colors show up. Basically, some colors are showing very bright, and others as black. I read somewhere that this might have something to do with the smooth shading and subdivision surface, but I disabled smooth shading and nothing changed. I tried adding the filmic log base encoder but the same result occurred.

[image: Render Colors]
In the image here you can see the way the colors are supposed to look. That brown in the render is supposed to be almost black. The red is way overexposed, while the skin is completely black.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is this still the case if you increase the lights (sun, ambient occlusion, world)?

Comment: The black effect is the same regardless of light. Even at 1000 power from a sun light, the black is still pitch black. The other colors get toned down some, but they really shouldn't be that bright at one or two brightness

Comment: Several materials or textures?

Comment: Oh wait. I reopened the project (after saving both the scene and image) and the color from the objects that were black are gone from both. I will look in to this more.

Comment: @lemon no, one material, one texture

Comment: Save your image (not saved in the screen capture). Also, where the yellow part comes from? Nothing is yellow on this image (the pants should be black).

Comment: I think it has something to do with way overexposing. The pants are a very dark brown, and reflecting a ton of light on that might make it look yellow.

Comment: Clear split normals read [Strange black shading. Cannot fully light mesh. (Cycles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles/76518#76518)