# Backwards normal issues

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have a 3D model of a car and some of the normal are wrong.

I can not seem to fix them easily. It is a high poly model so individualy selecting the faces and fixing them is out of the question. I have recalculated the normals about 5 times but still it's not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles

Answer (score 1):

If recalculating the normals via ctrl-n or shift-ctrl-n, on individual linked pieces, doesn't work correctly, you have bigger problems than discontiguous normals.  You probably have geometry that is non-manifold in other ways-- zero length edges, doubles, edges joining more than 2 faces, etc.  Use ctrl-shift-alt-m in edit/vertex mode, disable non-contiguous on the operator panel, and start cleaning up your mesh.