# No Light in final Render

Tags: lighting

When I look at the render preview it shows up lit and I have the lamp active on the same layer. I don't know what happened and it seems that all the settings are the same as a new file.

[image: final render]

Here's it supposed to look like in texture mode.

[image]

Comment: Probably custom normals if you e.g imported object from somewhere or used some modifiers. Try to open Properties editor > Object data tab > Custom Split Normals rollout and remove the layer there. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles. As another possibility it could be caused by material setup, it might help if you include it

Comment: Thanks! it was something with the material, I think i switched the material and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't assigned materials. Light power (emission) is not high enough. Try 5000 as emission/power.

Comment: I can clearly see a green and a white material.