# Certain vertices and edges are discolored (2.79b)

Tags: modeling, light

I've been wrestling with some free assets that refuse to render correctly no matter what I do. Currently I have a blend file with many imported glTF files, they all seem to render properly enough except for vertex-specific lighting issues that I can't seem to iron out.

Before this, I had tried using the OBJ and FBX files that came with this package and there were a couple bizarre lighting issues- Firstly, whenever I tried to add lighting or shadows the light would go on the side opposite the light source and would overlap with the shadows. I had imported the models into Godot but this also happened in Blender. The second issue was that when I tried to edit the meshes in blender the lighting would go nuts. I'm curious about this but it's not entirely relevant to this specific question.

[image: Weird Lighting in Godot]

[Here is the package I am using](https://opengameart.org/content/nature-kit) if you want to look yourself.

Currently these glTF assets are all free-floating triangles save for the ones I have edited so I am going through manually and removing duplicate vertices on each model. Some of the models have discoloration on specific vertices that I know aren't normal issues (tried recalculating normals many times) and don't all disappear if I separate the meshes or fiddle with shading modes (sharp , smooth). This specific model, a canoe, had a lot of issues but I have fixed all but two very persistent vertices that are greyer than normal in edit and lighter than normal in render.

[image: Discolored Vertices]

This is Material shading but in Solid and Rendered the discoloration is a more subtle gradation, yet still annoying. This is in Cycles Render, also.

Here is the .blend:

[image]

If anyone can tell me how to make the coloration normal throughout the model that would be very appreciated!

EDIT: Turns out every single model from this source had messed up lighting (OBJ files too) because they had Custom Split Normals Data. I don't know what that is but dang is it annoying to remove it from every single model and then re-export!

Comment: The geometry of the boat is messed up, especially in those regions, causing these discolorations

Comment: That's very vague. Could you be any more specific?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/igK9deE Here is one hole in the mesh, that is not immediately visible. Whats actually causing the dark normal faces, i'm not sure, but clearing the "Custom Split Normals Data " fixes your problem (at least on the boat),  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles

Comment: This is because the problem persisted whether it was attached or not- not relevant. Thanks for the advice